# How to change (or remove) wsdl input element name attribute in CXF?

Tags: soap, cxf

I'm using CXF to create SOAP services, The CXF created wsdl fragment as follows:

```
<wsdl:operation name="ping">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://www.example.org/ex/ping" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="ping">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="pingResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

Because of reasons of legacy systems, I need to remove the input element attribute name as follow:

```
<wsdl:operation name="ping">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://www.example.org/ex/ping" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

How to CXF whether to support such a deal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to remove that.  Those names shouldn't have any impact on the soap messages or anything so I'm not exactly sure why you would need to remove them.  Worst case, grab the WSDL and copy it locally for those systems and run an xslt on it to remove the names.